# Unable to locate ansible.cfg file

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to create a local config file in my ansible but when I run the list-hosts command its unable to locate it.

[image]

Comment: not that this that crucial atm, but any the reason you posted plain text content as image?

Comment: I took the snapshot to show the error in different color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-i` switch is for inventory, why do you feed config file into it?

Either use `ansible -i dev` or don't specify `-i` at all to use configured value from `ansible.cfg`.

Comment: when I dont specify -i and try this ansible --list-hosts all ...it says 'no hosts matched'

Comment: run `ansible -vv --list-hosts all` to ensure that expected `ansible.cfg` is used.

Comment: vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/ansible$ ansible -vv --list-hosts all
No hosts matched..Still same result.

Comment: It got fixed after a fresh install.